Serre functors and global dimensions
Let $k$ be a field.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian category (over $k$).
We say that $\mathcal{C}$ has a finite global dimension if there exists integer $n > 0$ such that
$$
\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N) =0 
$$
for $i>n$ and for any $M,N \in \mathcal{C}$.
In algebraic geometry, global dimensions of the categories of coherent sheaves are related to smoothness of varieties.
We always assume that $k$ is algebraically closed from here.
Let $X$ be a projective variety.
Then, $X$ is smooth if and only if the global dimension of $\operatorname{Coh}(X)$ is finite.
Moreover, smoothness is related to Serre functors.
$X$ is smooth if and only if $D^b(\operatorname{Coh}(X))$ has a Serre functor.
My question is the following:
Question If $D^b(\mathcal{C})$ has a Serre functor, then the global dimension of $\mathcal{C}$ is finite ?
In particular, I am interested in the case of $\mathcal{C} = \operatorname{qgr}(A)$.
$\operatorname{qgr}(A)$ is the quotient category of $\operatorname{gr}(A)$ by $\operatorname{tor}(A)$, where $A$ is an connected $\mathbb{N}$-graded right noetherian $k$-algebra, $\operatorname{gr}(A)$ is the category of finitely generated graded right $A$-modules and $\operatorname{tor}(A) \subset \operatorname{gr}(A)$ is the category of torsion $A$-modules.
It is known that $D^b(\operatorname{qgr}(A))$ has a Serre functor if $\operatorname{qgr}(A)$ has a finite global dimension and $A$ has a balanced  complex $R$.
In this case, the Serre functor is given by $-\otimes^{\mathbb{L}}R[-1]$(Appendix in Naeghel-Van den Bergh).
For a right and left notherian connected graded ring $A$, a dualizing complex of $A$ is a graded bi $A$-module $R$ such that

$R$ has finite injective dimensions as left and right $A$-modules.
the cohomology of $R$ is given by bimodules which are finitely generated on both sides.
The natural morphisms $A \rightarrow Hom_A(R,R)$ and $A \rightarrow Hom_{A^{\text{op}}}(R,R)$ are isomorphisms in $D^b(A^{\text{en}})$.

When a dualizing complex satisfies certain conditions, it is said to be balanced.
For details, see section 6 in Van den Bergh.
Any comments are welcome! Thank you.

The paper [Ueyama 2013 Graded maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules over noncommutative graded Gorenstein isolated singularities] (doi link) seems to be relavant. Corollary 4.5 says that for an AS-Gorenstion algebra, smoothness of qgr is equivalent to the existence of a Serre functor of the form $-\otimes^L R[-1]$.

Let $F$ be a Serre functor on $D^b(\mathcal{C})$. Then we have
$$\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(M,N[i])\cong 
\operatorname{Hom}(N[i],FM)^*\cong\operatorname{Hom}(N,FM[-i])^*.$$
So for $i$ larger than the top degree of $FM$, $\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,-)$ is zero. The problem is to make the bound global. Without further conditions, this is not true, because you can just let $\mathcal{C}$ be a direct sum of categories with Serre functors, but of larger and larger global dimensions. A sufficient condition is that $\mathcal{C}$ is generated in a finite number of steps by a finite set of objects. In qgr$(A)$, if the object $A$ itself is such a generator, then this holds.

Thank you. You mean that even if $D^b(\operatorname{qgr}(A))$ has a Serre functor and $A$ has a dualizing complex, it is not true that the global dimension of $\operatorname{qgr}(A)$ is finite ?

I don't think I said that. I merely gave you a condition to check, that implies finite global dimension. Constructing an $A$ where this conclusion fails is a different task.

Thank you for explaining that. I understand

And if $\cal C$ is generated in a finite number of steps by a finite set of objects each of finite degree, this suffices regardless whether there is a Serre functor or not, right? Or does this imply existence of the Serre functor?
